# How are video and audio synchronized by live555 framwork?

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, rtp, live555

when video and audio are made into **RTP** package ,and then **sending-end** sends RTP packages to **receiving-end**. I want to know that which end is this synchronized process made? sending-end or receiving-end ?

Answer (score 1):

Audio and video are sent in separate RTP sessions each with their own random timestamp offset. They are synchronised at the receiver using RTCP Sender Reports (SR) sent by the sender. RTCP SRs map the RTP timestamps of an RTP session (e.g. video or audio) to an NTP timestamp allowing the receiver to synchronise audio and video. This is all specified in [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550). The book by Colin Perkins "[RTP: Audio and Video for the Internet](https://books.google.co.za/books/about/RTP.html?id=OM7YJAy9_m8C&redir_esc=y)" has an excellent description of many aspects of RTP including synchronisation.